# How can I run jupyter notebook as .sh executable in Ubuntu?

Tags: sh, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter-notebook

I have a lot of `.ipynb` file stored in one folder. I have create a `.sh` file which contain only code `jupyter notebook`. Then I have change the preference > behavior in nautilus file manager to *ask each time*. Then when I double click the `.sh` file the box appear and I select run from terminal. But It is not executing and not opening then `jupyter notebook`. but if I do with terminal code it works as follows:

`chmod +x /path/to/ipynbStart.sh`

`./ipynbStart.sh`

I do the first approach with `.bat` file in windows and it works fine. I tried a lot But I could not find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not that difficult. I just create a new sh file (jupyter-start.sh) with the following command in the project directory I wanted:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
sh -c /home/datapsycho/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

In the third line it's the path to the jupyter-notebook in my system.
Then run the `chmod +x jupyter-start.sh` to make it executable. Now I can place that file to all my project folders where I need to start jupyter notebook and it will always start in the specific project directory I want.

Now every time I just can execute that program to start jupyter notebook with out writing any thing in the shell.